# How to make my Android app California Consumer Privacy Act compliance?

Tags: android, admob

As you read [this article](https://support.google.com/admob/answer/9561022), you may that you have to pass below parameter to restrict personal data processing for California users.

```
networkExtrasBundle.putInt("rdp", 1);
```

So there are two solutions (I have posted my questions below both):

Publishers must decide for themselves when and how to enable restricted data processing mode, based on their own compliance obligations and legal analysis. Two common scenarios are below.

1. Some publishers may choose not to display a “Do Not Sell My Personal Information” link on their properties. Such publishers may choose to enable restricted data processing for all of their programmatic traffic for users in California via a network control. If they select this option, Google will use user IP addresses to determine the location of users and enable restricted data processing mode for any users we can detect have a California IP address.

   - That means developer can always pass "1" and google will automatically take care of that ? Or else how to work for above solutions.
2. Alternatively, other publishers may choose to display a “Do Not Sell My Personal Information” link. Such publishers may choose to send a restricted data processing signal on a per-request basis once a user has opted out of the sale of their personal information. (See the Android & iOS developer documentation to learn more.)

   - How to determine that user is from California ?

Everything is confusing and there is no any help on internet about that.

Comment: As far as i understand, we have 2 options.

Either restrict personalized ads and revenue will probably drop dramatically, or do not restrict and ask users to share personal information with third parties.(Depending on the users answer, rdp parameter will be true or false)

Most of apps are already required to provide privacy policy in their apps and store page because of advertisementId.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two options.

1. Either you block collecting personal information from admob itself. It will deliver non personalized ads to all California user.
2. If you want to control ad serving parameter (personalized and non-personalized) by passing `"rdp"` parameter as shown above in question on each ad request, you have to write your own logic to determine whether user is from California or not. If user is from California then you can show alert stating that whether we can collect personal info for ad purpose or not and based on user action/input you can pass this parameter. There is no build in mechanism like for EU user, admob is providing Consent Form in its SDK.

Hope it clear the doubts of all developers like me. If anything please post in comment, I will try to answer.

Answer (score 0):

Google's guidance on this is very poor so far.

For 1. I thought "via a network control" meant that I would find a control in our admob account to enable it.  But there wasn't.

For 2. i had the same question and left feedback for Google.

Answer (score 0):

I have created a custom consent form similar to the european form.
(See the image below the page)
https://developers.google.com/admob/android/eu-consent

If user accepts to see personalized ads I send rdp 0 else rdp 1

I am not sure if it is true, since it is a global form and displayed to all users who has not purchased remove ads. I will not publish it to prod just yet. I will wait a little more. (Currently I have restricted on admob UI)

Comment: OK thank you for your response and creating like EU user consent dialog screen. When you are ready to publish, just paste the link here. it will really help a lot to all other developers as well. One question for you, which mechanism you used to detect whether user is from California or not ?

Comment: As I said, it is global and I don't use anything to detect user location. That is why I did not publish it just yet. I am not sure which users are considered in california.

1-Is geolocation enough?
2-Should California citizens should be included in, even if they are not currently in California?

These kind of questions are still unanswered. I will wait for an official update for this matter.